TypeDocに表示されているアイコン（記号？）が何を表しているかわからない
最近少しTypeScriptを触り始めたのですが、SDKのドキュメントなどのAPIドキュメントで以下のような形式のページを目にします。
https://typedoc.org/example/
このページの左側に「C」「E」「F」「I」などのアイコンのようなものが表示されていますが、この意味がわかりません。
なんとなくClassやInterfaceなどの頭文字なのかなという気はするのですが、この辺りの情報がまとまったページなどはあるでしょうか？

このIssue Legend with Icons at bottom of the page missing #2252 が仕様や説明ではありませんが、同じ話題に関連した情報を含んでいそうです。

class とか interface とか function とか enum とか。
